# React Dropzone cancel file upload on a button click

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm using [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) to upload files to my server in my react app. Everything is working great but I want to add a feature where if a file is taking too long to upload due to its size, the user can cancel the process with the click of a button.

```
<Dropzone 
  multiple={ false }
  accept={ allowedMimeTypes }
  onDrop={ this.onDrop }
  onDragEnter={ this.onDragEnter }
  onDragLeave={ this.onDragLeave }
  className={ classes.dropzone }
  maxSize={ MAX_UPLOAD_BYTES }
  >
</Dropzone>
<button onClick={ this.onCancelUpload }>Cancel</button>
```

Please advise, if It is possible using react-dropzone. I can't think of a way to stop the event that is already triggered and is uploading the file.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Hey beek check my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the above problem using the [Axios Cancel Token](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation).

1. Use Axios to handle the upload as a promise.
2. Create a source at the start of your code.

```js
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let source = CancelToken.source();
```

3. Pass on the source to the request in config.

```js
const {
  acceptedFiles
} = this.state;

const uploaders = acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  // data must be set BEFORE sending file
  formData.append('document', file);

  const uploadConfig = {
    onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
      const progressUpload = (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total;
      this.setState({
        progressUpload
      });
    },
    cancelToken: source.token,
  };

  return inkerzApi.post('/uploads/file', formData, uploadConfig)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(() => console.log('Upload canceled'));
});

Promise.all(uploaders).then((filesMetadata) => {
  filesMetadata.forEach((metadata) => {
    if (metadata && metadata.mediaLink && metadata.totalPages) {
      this.onNewFileUploaded(metadata);
      // show success message here
    } else if (this.state.uploadCanceled) {
      // show cancelation notification here
      this.setState({
        uploadCanceled: false
      });
    }
  });
  this.setState({
    acceptedFiles: [],
    progressUpload: 0,
  });
});
```

4. On Cancel Button Click

```js
onCancelUpload = () => {
        source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
        source = CancelToken.source();
        this.setState({ uploadCanceled: true });
    }
```

This worked out for me. Hope this helps others as well.

Comment: `source = CancelToken.source();` - for what you generate new source token after cancel?